# Text in WPF application appears unreadable or does not appear at all under VMWare

Tags: wpf, fonts, vmware

I've got a user running my WPF app on a Mac with VMWare, In Win 7, and most of the text in the app is unreadable.  I've ran this on my own VMWare-MacBook pro setup, and it seems to be fine.  Here's a screenshot from the user:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCzwn.png

The font for the missing or illegible text I expect should be Segoe UI, as is the text for the words "Combat Manager" that appear in a larger size on the screen, although I have not explicitly set the font face.

Any idea what the cause might be?

Comment: Try turning off WPF hardware acceleration. It might be doing weird things with the virtual GPU.

Comment: Have you tried changing themes?

Comment: Disabling HW acceleration using HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics DisableHWAcceleration = 1 fixed the problem.  I would rather it have been something I could fix in code, but it gives me a way to help my users.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When we had this and other issues with some of our test staff, it was because they had the memory settings turned too low for the video emulation to handle WPF.  VMWare defaults to somewhere around 256 MB for total RAM for the guest OS.  Try turning that up to 2 GB or higher.  You can also tinker with the video settings for the VM.  In addition, check the font size and DPI settings on the guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest VMWare Workstation software and install the latest VMWare tools.  There was a version of 7.0.x that had this issue.  In our case you couldn't see the text at all.

Answer (score 1):

My VMWare version: 7.1.4
OS: Windows 7 x86

Had the same issue, the solution for me was to update the WMVare Tools to the latest version (as of today). (VMware Tools version 8.4.6)